# I need returns the average hourly rate between two dates in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, average

I need to write a query [ aggregate ]  that returns the average hourly rate between two dates in Mongodb.

I found in my research the following code

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      transactionDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2017-01-31T23:59:59.000Z")
      }    
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      average_transaction_amount: {
        $avg: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

The previous code returns the average one value between two dates,but I need Average per hour.

sample document is

```
{"_id":"5a4e1fa1e4b02d76985c39b1",
"temp1":4,
"temp2":3,
"temp3‌​":2,
"created_on":"20‌​18-01-04T12:35:45.83‌​3Z"}
```

Result for example :

```
{ {temp1:5,temp2:6,temp3:6} for Average hour {temp1:2,temp2:4,temp3:6}for Average hour next ,{temp1:5,temp2:7,temp3:9},{temp1:8,temp2:4,temp3:7},{temp1:‌​4,temp2:2,temp3:6},{‌​temp1:9,temp2:6,temp‌​3:4}
 }
```

Between every hour there are a lot of values ,So I need to calculate the Avg per hour

Please help

Comment: Can you add sample document and expected json response ?

Comment: yes >>  sample document  is {"_id":"5a4e1fa1e4b02d76985c39b1","temp1":4,"temp2":3,"temp3":2,"created_on":"2018-01-04T12:35:45.833Z"}

Comment: Result for example :{  **{temp1:5,temp2:6,temp3:6} for Average  hour** {temp1:2,temp2:4,temp3:6}for Average  hour next ,{temp1:5,temp2:7,temp3:9},{temp1:8,temp2:4,temp3:7},{temp1:4,temp2:2,temp3:6},{temp1:9,temp2:6,temp3:4} }

Comment: Between every hour there are a lot of values

Comment: Please add all the details to question . Can you try `{
    $group: {
      _id: {$hour:"$transactionDate"},
      temp: {
        $avg: "$temp1"
      }
    }
  }`. Repeat for other fields.

Comment: So I need to calculate the Avg per hour

Comment: @Majedjemmieh have you considered running the query once per hour?(changing the gte and lte dates to increment hourly)

Comment: Thank for all , I found ANSWER is [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: Thank you  @Veeram